# Difference between software inspection and verification

Tags: quality, verification

I was reading about software inspection in Software Engineering by Ian Summerville and I came across the term Software inspection and I started reading about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_inspection). I am unable to understand what is the difference between verification and software inspection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Software verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_verification) is the collection of methods used to determine if the software system that is being constructed is being built right. Some aspect of the system, whether it's the design, the implementation, or the test cases, are compared to the documented requirements of the system.

A [software inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_inspection) is a particular technique that can be used to verify the system against the specification. There are different types of inspections, ranging from a "desk check" where another developer looks over the work product to a formal inspection (often called a [Fagan inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagan_inspection)) with roles, checklists, and meetings, with many formats of inspections falling between these two extremes.

Comment: So, software inspection is a type of verification?

Comment: @www.AppTec.net Yes, it is.